# Android using J2ME native

Tags: android, java-me, native

Is here some posibility how to use J2ME natives in android? I imported library which calls natives like:

```
 public static native synchronized javax.microedition.contactless.DiscoveryManager getInstance();
```

When I am calling

```
DiscoveryManager dm = DiscoveryManager.getInstance();
```

in my activity, I got runtime exception:

```
 java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError: Native method not found: javax.microedition.contactless.DiscoveryManager.getInstance:()Ljavax/microedition/contactless/DiscoveryManager;
```

Does I do somewhere a mistake or I need somehow to load J2ME native library (and if yes, how can I do it)?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can load your native library i.e.

```
System.loadLibrary("Your_Library_name");
```

and your library should be loaded before calling any native method.

Comment: java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError: Couldn't load jsr257: findLibrary returned null  and I just simply copied name of library to System.loadLibrary("jsr257") and for no of my libraries this load works.

Comment: can you post your code sample because your question is not so clear to understand.

Comment: thanks you, ur point led me to source of my problem. I was badly linking native library.